# How can I solve this problem in IONIC typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have a problem in my typescript code for ionic project , im trying to get the value of the variable ( this.currentroom ) from Fuction getCurrentRoom()  to another function ( get user()) but failed
what the problem , here is my chat service .ts :

```
 public getCurrentRoom()  {
    this.afs.collection('users',ref => ref.where("email", "==", this.currentUser.email)).get().toPromise()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        this.currentRoom=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(doc.data())).room;
        console.log("current room"+this.currentRoom);
      });
  });


  }
   
   public getUsers()
   {
      this.getCurrentRoom();
      console.log("this room"+this.currentRoom);
      return this.afs.collection('users',ref => ref.where("room", "==", this.currentRoom)).valueChanges({ idField: 'uid' }) as Observable<User[]>;

   }
```

Comment: You're making a promise, which will take some time to resolve it to either success or failure. That is the cause you aren't able to access this.currentRoom immediately after calling getcurrentroom method

Comment: how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `async` and `await` which will tell JavaScript to wait for asynchronous method.

```
public async getCurrentRoom() {
    await this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where("email", "==", this.currentUser.email)).get().toPromise()
        .then(snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                this.currentRoom = doc.data().room;
                console.log("current room" + this.currentRoom);
            });
        });
}

public async getUsers() {
    await this.getCurrentRoom();
    console.log("this room" + this.currentRoom);
    return this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where("room", "==", this.currentRoom)).valueChanges({
        idField: 'uid'
    }) as Observable < User[] > ;
}
```

Comment: i just edited my question and include the function

Comment: Modern JS / TS supports `async` and `await`. Have you tried including that in your functions?